# Magento 2.2.3 - Customizable Product Options Display in Cart But Not on Sales Order

Tags: magento2, configurable-product, custom-options

When ordering a product and selecting its customizable product options, these product options appear in the cart/checkout. After placing the order, the customizable product options do not appear on the sales order nor the sales order email sent to the customer. If anyone has faced this issue or can give me insight on how to fix this issue that would be awesome. Thank you.

[image: Screenshot: Product Options Display in Checkout]

[image: Screenshot: Product Options DO NOT Display in Sales Email]

[image: Screenshot: Product Options DO NOT Display in Admin Sales Order]